# sed or awk: group by paragraphs consisting of 2nd upto n+1th lines of each paragraph

Tags: awk, sed

I need to count the number of same subparagraphs in a threaddump. I am not able to use sed to extract the 2nd *upto* n+1th line of each subparagraph. awk is also ok to use

For example, given the following sample threaddump.txt

```
"RMI TCP Accept-0" Id=11 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:400)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:372)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"AMQP Connection 10.170.10.128:5672" Id=227 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-10.104.42.237-16210-exec-12" Id=90 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:519)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1048)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Signal Dispatcher" Id=6 RUNNABLE

"kafcli-poller-10" Id=277 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:686)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:408)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:261)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1171)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(zk0007.svc.prod.wd1.wd:2181)" Id=59 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:345)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1214)
```

If n=3, the output will be (please note the count at the beginning of each substack):

```
2   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)

2   at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)

1   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
```

Because

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
```

appears twice in the threaddump; and so on and so forth.

This is a three step process:

1. Extract all RUNNABLE paragraghs, aka RUNNABLE stacks. This is successfully accomplished using the following [syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136218/grep-sed-or-awk-print-entire-paragraph-in-a-file-on-pattern-match):

`cat threaddump.txt | sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/ RUNNABLE/!d;' > RUNNABLE.txt`

2. For each stack (or paragraph), extract the 2nd *upto* n+1th line. I've tried many different combinations of the following, attempting to use sed's "q" option to select lines but to no avail. I won't list all the other attempts based on these [examples](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt). awk would also work but not able to get the holding pattern from sed into awk.

`cat RUNNABLE.txt | sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/{2q}/!d;'`

3. Finally, group by the subparagraphs. I haven't gotten that far. But my plan is to collapse each substack into one line by removing the newlines, then use *sort* followed by *uniq -c*.

Comment: I tried awk; but I couldn't get the output of sed's holding pattern into awk.

Comment: Do you have GNU sed/awk/tools?

Comment: yep. I do. btw, the group by 'key' in this case is multi-lines. Hence, the count represents how many times this pattern of multi-lines show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
# extract first fields from each group
awk -v RS='' -v FS='\n' -v n=3 'NF > n { for (i = 2; i <= n + 1; ++i) print $i; printf "%c", "\0" }' |
# sort and uniq
sort -z | uniq -zc | sort -zrnk1 |
# some messy output formatting
sed 's/\x00//g; s/^ *\([0-9]\+\) */#\n\1#/; 1s/^#\n//; s/^ *at/#at/' | column -t -s'#' -o '   '
```

outputs:

```
2   at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)

2   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)

1   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
```

- Record Separator is set to an empty line. That way I have each paragraph read at once by `awk`, as they are separated by an empty line. Field Separator to one line. So in each paragraph each line is easily accessible with a separate `$num` variable. Then I just output  the lines from `2` to `n+1` to extract the lines from each paragraph. The lines are suffixed with a zero byte.
- `sort -z | uniq -zc` computes the count then.
- `sort -zrnk1` then just sorts it using the numbers that `uniq` outputted.
- Then the messy `sed` piped to `column` is used to do a nice columnized output.

Comment: Thank you! it worked just like you said. I'm going thru it now to understand what you did